# PLSQL 10g- create a list of strings

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have been researching this for a while. I have a Dataset below, and I need the desired out out to be in a list of strings. If there is a duplicate Product I want it to go on a seperate row. what the below gets me is all of the customerid and products on one line. I want if there are duplicates make the duplicate on anothe line. Please let me know if there are any questions.

```
With CustomerData as (
select
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY Product) rn,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ) cnt
from Customers)
select 
ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(customerid,','),','),
ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(Product,','),',') AS Product,
from CustomerData 
where rn = cnt 
start with rn = 1 
connect by prior customerid = customerid
and prior rn = rn1 


customerid | CustomerName | Product | date 
1            Bob            9         3-14-2016
1            Bob            10        3-14-2016       
1            Bob            9         3-12-2016
2            Brad           1         3-14-2016
2            Brad           3         3-14-2016
3            Sam            1         3-14-2016
3            Sam            1         3-12-2016
3            Sam            5         3-14-2016
```

Desired Output

```
customerid   CustomerName      Product   
1, 1         BOB, BOB         9, 10
1,           BOB              9
2, 2         Brad, Brad       1, 3
3, 3         Sam, Sam         1, 5
3            Sam              1
```

Comment: I cant I am running on 10 g

Comment: The LISTAGG function can be used in the following versions of Oracle/PLSQL:
•Oracle 12c, Oracle 11g Release 2

Comment: in 10g there's an undocumanted way of doing this called `wm_concat()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate string connection in Oracle 10g](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190598/aggregate-string-connection-in-oracle-10g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using the undocumented (and unsupported) `WMSYS.WM_CONCAT` function (that is not available on all systems and is [not available at all on Oracle 12c](https://blogs.oracle.com/oracle-database-app-admin/entry/why_not_use_wm_concat)) you can do it using collections and the `COLLECT` aggregation function.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR2s_Table AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION concatStrings(
  Strs VARCHAR2s_Table,
  delim VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN CLOB
AS
  out_string CLOB;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. Strs.COUNT LOOP
    out_string := out_string || CASE WHEN i = 1 THEN '' ELSE delim END || Strs(i);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN out_string;
END;
/
```

**Query**

```
SELECT concatStrings( CAST( COLLECT( TO_CHAR( cust_id ) ) AS VARCHAR2s_Table ) ) AS cust_ids,
       concatStrings( CAST( COLLECT( cust_name ) AS VARCHAR2s_Table ) ) AS cust_names,
       concatStrings( CAST( COLLECT( TO_CHAR( prod_id ) ) AS VARCHAR2s_Table ) ) AS prod_ids
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY cust_id, order_dt;
```

**Output**:

```
CUST_IDS              CUST_NAMES            PROD_IDS
--------------------- --------------------- ---------------------
1                     Bob                   9
1,1                   Bob,Bob               9,10
2,2                   Brad,Brad             1,3  
3                     Sam                   1
3,3                   Sam,Sam               1,5
```

Comment: MTO - What does this line do? CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR2s_Table AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

Comment: Creates a [table type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/collection.htm#CJAFJBHF) which can be use to store a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm) (similar to an array in other languages) that, in this instance, can be used to perform string aggregation.

Comment: so its a temp/perm table to store the data to use within the function?

Comment: No, in this example, it is not a table; it is an in-memory (array) structure that can be used in SQL and in PL/SQL procedures & functions. However, it could be used as a datatype for a column of a table (see [nested tables](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE)) or as a [bind variable to allow external languages to pass an array into a query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264).

Answer (score 1):

On Oracle 10 you should be able to use the wmsys.wm_concat function, although do be aware that the return datatype is a CLOB and not a varchar:

```
WITH the_Data as (
select 1 cust_id,           'Bob' cust_name,           9 prod_id,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 1,            'Bob',            10,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all       
select 1,            'Bob',            9,        to_Date('3-12-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 2,            'Brad',           1,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 2,            'Brad',           3,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 3,            'Sam',            1,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 3,            'Sam',            1,        to_Date(' 3-12-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 3,            'Sam',            5,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual 
)
select wm_concat(cust_id)
      ,wm_concat(cust_name)
      ,wm_concat(prod_id) 
 from the_Data
group by order_dt, cust_id
order by cust_id, order_Dt  

WM_CONCAT(CUST_ID),WM_CONCAT(CUST_NAME),WM_CONCAT(PROD_ID)
1                 Bob                  9
1,1               Bob,Bob              9,10
2,2               Brad,Brad            1,3
3                 Sam                  1
3,3               Sam,Sam              1,5
```

If you don't have access to this (it is not a supported function nor always installed), then you can implement [Tom Kyte's STRAGG user-defined analytic as shown here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402)

Other than that, you wind up going into XML processing as an option:

```
WITH the_Data as (
select 1 cust_id,           'Bob' cust_name,           9 prod_id,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 1,            'Bob',            10,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all       
select 1,            'Bob',            9,        to_Date('3-12-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 2,            'Brad',           1,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 2,            'Brad',           3,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 3,            'Sam',            1,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 3,            'Sam',            1,        to_Date(' 3-12-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual union all
select 3,            'Sam',            5,        to_Date('3-14-2016','mm-dd-yyyy') order_dt from dual 
)
select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,cust_id,',').extract('//text()')),',') cus_ids
      ,rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,cust_name,',').extract('//text()')),',') cus_names
      ,rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,prod_id,',').extract('//text()')),',') prod_ids
 from the_Data
group by order_dt, cust_id
order by cust_id, order_Dt ;

cus_ids,      cus_names,    prod_ids    
1             Bob           9
1,1           Bob,Bob       9,10
2,2           Brad,Brad     1,3
3             Sam           1
3,3           Sam,Sam       1,5
```

Comment: I see that you are doing a select on the data. There will be a ton more data and I really will only know the column names. Is there a way to do it by selecting cust_id, cust_name, prod_id with out the data specified?

Comment: The WITH the_data AS() is just a way for me to build a temporary table in memory for example's sake. You will just query your table as normal.

Comment: that def works with the example data, it does get a little goofey with just a query but Im sure its just something i am doing.

Comment: IF you can write the query to extract the data as per the example, plop that into the WITH clause and the rest will work.